# PHP-cli. Reducing memory usage

Tags: php, memory, command-line-interface, ram

I have a CentOS7 server with a small amount of RAM that has a dozen users who run some cli php script from terminal with php command time by time. With a default php config every execution of the script takes about 10MB of RAM. Are there any tools or approaches that could reduce the memory usage in this case?

The script is quite simple and compact (about 4kb, it uses Mysqli and Curl modules and some basic I/O operations. No frameworks.

I don't use opcache. Could you suggest me if it worths to be turned on in order to solve my problem? My guess that this would affect only on CPU performance.

Answer (score 0):

for best performance use `CentOS minimal`
also 32bit version is better than 64bit
dont install plugins that never use
mysql use a lot of memory
i use `sqlite` many years, its very nice, without momery usage
its good even for big sites